# Mixture of button selection and text replies from telegram bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to create simple TG bot, where first interaction is by clicking on button and next be entering text. In `ConversationHandler` I'm following multiple examples available and using both, `CallbackQueryHandler` to handle click on button and `MessageHandler` to process text response.
However, click on buttons does not save the gender. Instead when printing the `user_data`, it shows something like `<telegram.callbackquery.CallbackQuery object at 0x7fc2d82c8190>`.
Will appreciate if someone can show what's wrong with below listing.

```
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler, CallbackQueryHandler)
from telegram import (Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup)

GENDER, NAME, AGE = 0, 1, 2

user_data = {}

def start_handler(update: Update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("M", callback_data=str(GENDER)),
            InlineKeyboardButton("F", callback_data=str(GENDER)),
        ]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text("Male / Female", reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return GENDER

def gender_handler(update: Update, context):
    user_data[GENDER] = update.callback_query
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text("enter name")
    return NAME

def name_handler (update: Update, context):
    user_data[NAME] = update.message.text
    update.message.reply_text("enter age")
    return AGE

def finish_handler(update: Update, context):
    user_data[AGE] = update.message.text
    print(user_data)
    update.message.reply_text(f"G: {user_data[GENDER]}, name: {user_data[NAME]}, age: {user_data[AGE]}")
    return ConversationHandler.END

def cancel_handler(update: Update, context):
    print("bye")

def main():
    updater = Updater(
        token="TOKEN",
        use_context=True,
    )

    dp = updater.dispatcher

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[
            CommandHandler("start", start_handler),
        ],
        states={
            GENDER: [CallbackQueryHandler(gender_handler)],
            NAME: [MessageHandler(Filters.all, name_handler)],
            AGE: [MessageHandler(Filters.all, finish_handler)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", cancel_handler)],
    )

    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

main()
```

Comment: This works fine for me … Which versions of `python-telegram-bot` and `python` are you using?

Comment: @CallMeStag, it doesn't show any errors for me as well, however if I see content of ```user_data``` it will not have proper information for "GENDER". Only name and age are there" ```{0: <telegram.callbackquery.CallbackQuery object at 0x7fc2d82c8190>, 1: 'Sergei', 2: '11'}``` Python 3.9.6, python-telegram-bot 13.11

Comment: I see. the question is a bit misleading, then: `However, click on buttons does not update anything.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

> `user_data[GENDER] = update.callback_query`

[`Update.callback_query`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.update.html?highlight=update.callback_query#telegram.Update.callback_query) is an instance of the class [`CallbackQuery`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.callbackquery.html#telegram.CallbackQuery). So you're saving the complete object to `user_data[GENDER]`, while what you want to know is only the selected gender. For this to work you should

1. update the keyboard such that each button has a unique `callback_data`
2. access [`update.callback_query.data`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.callbackquery.html#telegram.CallbackQuery.data) to check which button was pressed

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.